# how to map result value to its key value in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, combinations, array-map

I have 2 arrays first is data and 2nd is result array

i am trying to map result array with data array
so i used combine() method

but problem is that if i have same result then it map 1 item and skips remaining consider

**first array($customersidurl)**

```php
[
    19 => null,
    20 => null,
    21 => null,
    24 => "31.4346084,74.2793016,12",
    25 => null,
    26 => "31.58834,74.37375"
]
```

**second result array($shortest)**

```php
[
    0 => 8532.8587780495,
    1 => 8532.8587780495,
    2 => 8532.8587780495,
    3 => 18.831126689097,
    4 => 8532.8587780495,
    5 => 0.85071506409078
]
```

and my **output** is

```php
[
    "" => 8532.8587780495,
    31.4346084,74.2793016,12 => 18.831126689097,
    31.58834,74.37375 => 0.85071506409078,
]
```

**it skipped 3 results. I don't want that skipping to happen. The code I used is**

```php
$customersidurl = Customer::whereIn('created_by', $adminot)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('location_url', 'id');

foreach ($customersidurl as $short) {
    $shortest[] = $this->getsortedDistance($cords , $cords1 ,$short);
}

$combined = $customersidurl->combine($shortest);
```

can someone help me any other which can map each of elements with  corresponding?

required output is

```php
[
    "" => 8532.8587780495,
    "" => 8532.8587780495,
    "" => 8532.8587780495,
    31.4346084,74.2793016,12 => 18.831126689097,
    "" => 8532.8587780495,
    31.58834,74.37375 => 0.85071506409078
]
```

Comment: Can you please include what you're desired output is as it's currently not clear?

Comment: @dazed-and-confused thanx for your contribution i have updated question

Comment: Welcome to So. As you have 3 null values in your first result, it is normal to have one corresponding item in the result. You cannot have 2 same keys in an array.

Comment: About the question you just closed: `collect($a)->mapWithKeys(fn($i) => [explode(' => ', $i)[0] => explode(' => ', $i)[1]])->all()` should give you the result you seeked. Also, your required output shows `""` is repeated as a key. An array can't have two identical keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as you are passing ids

```
$customersidurl = Customer::whereIn('created_by', $adminot)->get()->pluck('location_url', 'id');
      
        foreach ($customersidurl as $short){
         $shortest[] = $this->getsortedDistance($cords , $cords1 ,$short);
        }
        $customersid = Customer::whereIn('created_by', $adminot)->pluck('id')->toArray();
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($customersid); $i++){
            $maping[$customersid[$i]] =  $shortest[$i];
        }
```